# Excel/Libreoffice returning TRUE for IF() instead of expression

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice

See the following situation:

[image]

For some

Here cells A1:E3 have plain text data (no formulas), and C4:E4 have the same formula (i.e. typed in one cell and then autofilled to another ones).

I wanted to make cells C4:E4 contain `__` if there's nothing in the two cells to the right of them in line 2, and average of 5 cells around corresponding cell in line 2 otherwise. What I get instead is `TRUE` for the formula I entered when test evaluates to true.

I get exactly the same behavior in Libreoffice (which was first I tried, and checked MSO thinking it's LibO bug).

What's happening here? Why do I get `TRUE` instead of the average?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the formatting of the cell `C4`. If it's `Boolean Value`, it will output `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of the expected formula result.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a simple Sum of a column of cells and got the "True" response.
I cleared the "True" by going to, Format > Clear Direct Formatting. 
I am using LibreOffice Version 5.2.3.3.