# LibreOffice Calc IF Function returns True when should return cell

Tags: mac, worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have been successfully using the IF function up until the last few days. I used this statement to return one of 2 values depending on whether or not an item is shaped:

```
=IF(G11=1,Q11,IF(G11=0,P11,""))
```

G11 is 1 (representing a yes) Instead of returning the value of Q11 it says TRUE.

I have tried breaking it down to just the one IF function, checking the structure of the formula. I've been getting around the problem by making new tables an replacing the IF with a VLOOKUP but that will not work here. What might be happening?

Comment: What is in Q11?

Comment: Another IF statement. It works out if an area of glass is below a minimum area, then if it is, it returns the minimum, if it is above it then it returns the area.

Comment: If G11 is either true or false, you should never get to the blank.  Your formula should be equivalent to =IF(G11=1,Q11,P11), or even =IF(G11,Q11,P11).  Do you get the same result if you simplify the formula?

Comment: In this case does the IF statement in Q11 work out to be 1?  If that is the problem then wrapping the entire IF statement in a `VALUE()` should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

it might be the cell formatting, if the Category is set to Boolean Value then  TRUE or FALSE is returned and not your "then" or "else" values. credit https://superuser.com/a/709505

Comment: Thats it! I don't know why the format changed for those cells. I was using the spreadsheet as an example for how I'd want a program to work, so it'll help the programmer a lot to have an example that works. Thanks byronic

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice and OpenOffice use a different [delimiter](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#Syntax_3) to Excel.

You should swap the comma to a semi-colon.

```
=IF(G11=1;Q11;IF(G11=0;P11;""))
```

EDIT: As pointed out by @fixer1234 you can [change the delimiter](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Formula_1#Separators) from the default `;` to `,`. You should check what yours is in the settings.

Comment: OpenOffice uses semi-colon.  The LO Calc delimiter matches Excel (it might be locale/language specific).  Despite what the link says, my (US English) LO Calc uses comma for the delimiter.  It does differ from Excel in that TRUE and FALSE gets changed to 1 and 0.

Comment: The delimiter can be set under main menu, Tools, Options, LibreOffice Calc, Formula, Separators.  On mine, the default setting is comma.